# Are we asking too much of transactional memory?

Tags: locking, transactional-memory, stm

I've been reading up a lot about transactional memory lately. There is a bit of hype around TM, so a lot of people are enthusiastic about it, and it does provide solutions for painful problems with locking, but you regularly also see complaints:

- You can't do I/O
- You have to write your atomic sections so they can run several times (be careful with your local variables!)
- Software transactional memory offers poor performance
- [Insert your pet peeve here]

I understand these concerns: more often than not, you find articles about STMs that only run on some particular hardware that supports some really nifty atomic operation (like [LL/SC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-Link/Store-Conditional)), or it has to be supported by some imaginary compiler, or it requires that *all* accesses to memory be transactional, it introduces type constraints monad-style, etc. And above all: these are real problems.

This has lead me to ask myself: **what speaks against local use of transactional memory as a replacement for locks?** Would this already bring enough value, or must transactional memory be used all over the place if used at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, some of the problems you mention can be real ones now, but things evolve.
As any new technology, first there is a hype, then the new technology shows that there are some unresolved problems, and then some of these problems are solved and others not. This result in another possibility to solve your problems, for which this technology is the more adapted.

I will say that you can use STM for a part of your application that can leave with the constraints the currents state of the art have. Part of the application that don't mind about a lost of efficiency for example.

Communication between the transaction and non transactional parts is the big problem. There are STM that are lock aware, so them can interact in a consistent way with non transactional parts.

I/O is also possible, but your transaction becomes irrevocable, that is, can not be aborted. That means that only one transaction can use I/O at the same time. You can also use I/O once the top level transaction has succeed, on a non-transactional world, as now.

Most of the STM library base systems force the user to make the difference between transactional and non transactional data. So yes, you need to understand what this exactly means. On the other hand, compilers can deduce what access must be transactional or not, the problem been that they can be too conservative, decreasing the efficiency we can get when we manage explicitly the different kind of variables. This is the same as having static, local and dynamic variables. You need to know the constraints each one have to make a correct program.

Answer (score 1):

> I've been reading up a lot about transactional memory lately.

You might also be interested in this [podcast on software transactional memory](http://se-radio.net/podcast/2007-09/episode-68-dan-grossman-garbage-collection-and-transactional-memory), which also introduces STM using an analogy based on garbage collection:

> The [paper](http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/djg/papers/analogy_oopsla07.pdf) is about an analogy between garbage collection and transactional memory. 
>   In addition to seeing the beauty of the analogy, the discussion also serves as a good 
>   introduction to transactional memory (which was mentioned in the Goetz/Holmes episode) 
>   and - to some extent - to garbage collection.

Comment: @none, that looks interesting.

Comment: Yep, I know that one - I also read the paper, which is very interesting (and prompted me to post another question on garbage collection performance).

Answer (score 0):

If you use transactional memory as a replacement for locks, all the code that executes with that lock held could be rolled back upon completion. Thus the code that was previously using locks must be transactional, and will have all the same drawbacks (and benefits).

So, you could possibly restrict the influence of TM to only those parts of the code that hold locks, right? Every piece of code that can be called during a held lock must support TM, in that scenario. How much of your program does not hold locks and is never called by code that holds locks?